# take the results of a google search

Tags: android, google-search

I am working on an Android application and I want make a search in google and save the results in a data structure in order to use them. Can someone indicate me an instrument that I can use? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just contact the google api for searching and parse the json or xml results, extracting exactly what information you want.[google-search](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)

Comment: Can you give me an example to use Google Custom Search API in my Android Application?

Comment: I have found only example of Web Appliction that use Google Custom Search API.. I have instead an Android Application..